# Disable video comments through the youtube API in Java

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How to disable comments when uploading a video with Youtube API, in java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick Google, I found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/a95bc779ac5cd943/22fcf4a09883db61?pli=1).

What you want to do is add an yt:accessControl element to the video entry, with an action attribute of "comment" and a permission attribute of "moderated". I don't believe that there is native support or the yt:accessControl element in the Java client library yet, so this would have to be done "by hand". Here's some example code that 
assumes you've just created a new video, and then performs a partial update to set the yt:accessControl value for that video:

```
VideoEntry createdEntry = service.insert(new URL(uploadUrl), newEntry);

String atomXml = "<?xml version='1.0'?><entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' gd:fields='yt:accessControl' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'><yt:accessControl action='comment' permission='moderated'/></entry>";

GDataRequest request = service.createPatchRequest(new URL(createdEntry.getEditLink().getHref()));
request.getRequestStream().write(atomXml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
request.execute();
createdEntry = service.parseResponseData(request, VideoEntry.class);

// createdEntry now contains the updated VideoEntry, and the access control should be set on it.
```

Comment: Please include the solution in the answer.

Comment: for me "createdEntry.getEditLink()" becomes null. Any idea why is that?